# SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php

Ayuda tengo este problema en mi código, quien me ayuda por favor 
este es el código:

```
function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
{                       
    require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;   
    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";                  
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';      
    $mail->Port       = 465;             
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->Username="micorreo";  
    $mail->Password="micontraseña";            
    $mail->SetFrom('micorreo@gmail.com','Coding Cage');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("micorreo@gmail.com","Coding Cage");
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail->Send();
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Enviado!";
    }
}
```

Me genera el siguiente error:

> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo esta [respuesta aceptada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16048485/236345), los posibles motivos por los que no se conecta al servidor SMTP pueden ser:

- Que sea necesario usar `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` en vez de ssl.
- Que el puerto sea 587
- Que el usuario o la contraseña estén incorrectos.

Adicional, yo usaría `$mail->IsHTML(true);` para especificar el formato en el que viaja el mensaje.

Answer (score 0):

veo que la configuración SMTP es correcta, el problema que tienes puede ser porque están mal las credenciales que usas del correo, que el correo no tenga configurado permisos para que aplicaciones lo utilicen para enviar email o que tu servidor no tenga configurado envíos de mail.

Me ha pasado con XAMPP en local que no me envía los correos, por mail() ni por SMTP, pero al mover mi aplicación a un servidor que estoy seguro está configurado funciona correctamente.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Para el envio de mail SMTP utiliza el puerto 587 y autentifican tls

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->Port = '587'; 
$mail->Username = 'tucuenta@gmail.com'; 
$mail->Password = '***';
```